# Building webrtc native on Ubuntu

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, webrtc, videochat

I am having a hard time building webrtc-native on ubuntu. The Build instructions for webrtc are wayward and poor. I am following https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/.

Figured that I need to install the depot tools and run `fetch v8`. Then I did `gclient sync`. Did `apt-get install ninja`. Now I am stuck at `python webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc`. I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc",
>   line 23, in 
>       import gyp_chromium ImportError: No module named gyp_chromium

I badly need help here. Also, it seems that the community doesn't care much about helping to build native apps using webrtc. The focus is on upstream/Web APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Please check https://github.com/HefnySco/node-webrtc-native

I hade very hard time. I used build-webrtc with some tweaks all listed on the above link.

The linked project goes one step forward and build a node component after building the webrtc lib.

Comment: Do you know from where the node component gets the media when invoking getUserMedia? Trying to understand their sample.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC recently moved from gyp to gn as the default method to generate ninja files.

You should find the process to get started easier here: https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/